# PHP Displaying of page issues

Tags: php, echo

It's a blank page and that's not how it's supposed to be :/

Can anyone help me out with this?

Code - http://pastie.org/private/9klk5tm6goixq4ev93tkq

-
Mord

Comment: Do you get any errors of any kind?

Comment: You must be joking. You post 700+ lines of code with a few partial sentences of what the issue is? Sorry, that's now how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need closing parenthesis on every line that has one opening.

Example:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["thematicseniorphoto"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["thematicseniorphoto"]["tmp_name"];
```

should be

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["thematicseniorphoto"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["thematicseniorphoto"]["tmp_name"]);
```

EDIT:

Next time use a while() statement and find a pattern of text to search/use.  You'll go from 700 lines to like...20.